# How to optimize and close a PDO connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i got a problem with my hosting, i'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000] [1226] User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 3)
```

Here is my PDO class http://pastebin.com/GaMecuPE

Can you guys tell me how to close the connection and optimize.
I've already tried to close the connection with closeCursor() after every function:

```
        // @query it get data from the database
public function query($sql, $data=array()) {
    $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute($data);
    return $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $req->cursorClose();
    $this->db = sleep(60);
}
```

but it didn't worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you know there's a difference between `cursorClose` and `closeCursor` right? I'd say the [latter is the good one](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php)

Comment: Yes, and i've tried also closeCursor and didn't worked too.

Comment: why write cursorClose? have you defined that function? Otherwise, as long as `cursorClose` is called this script will not execute, `cursorClose` should be an existing function...

Comment: it wouldn't be executed either way because of the `return`. And I'm a bit allergic to classes like `DB`, `Database` et.al.: Exactly what is it this class brings to the table?

Comment: I think issue with closing the cursor is a "side-show"... I it is likely the real issue is with misusing your `$db` You should only be using a single instance of $db, and you should be injecting it into any other classes that need to use it. This is likely why you have so many connections running because you keep doing `$dbOrSomeOtherVar = new DB();` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you RETURN from the method. Nothing after that will execute.

create a new function called close.

Then do:

```
db->query("");

db->close("");
```

Comment: put the close stuff in another function and call it when you are done with DB related things.

Comment: Can you explain, please? how to execute it, with the return ?